# getting secutiry permission on hostgator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, server-administration

We had developed an application in ASP.NET MVC 4,framework 4.0 with database as MY SQL
Version of dlls we had used:
MySQl.data.dll : 6.8.3
Nhibernate : 3.3.3
Newtonsoft.json :  4.5.11.15520
Fluent Nhibernate : 1.4.0.0

It's working perfectly fine on my local system but not working on Hostgator server.
It's not able to connect to database.we had used "log4net" for logging the errors, & getting the following error while connecting to database-

INFO 2014-05-31 02:54:24 Class:roundshopee.Models.DeverrorsRepository Method:IsDeverrorsExists Line #: 195   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Connection string we are using to connect to database is:

Data Source=localhost;User ID=group_roundshope;Password=g#s9Um09;persist security info=False;initial catalog=groupon_roundshopee;charset=utf8;Convert Zero Datetime=true;

I had checked the videos on your tutorial, but no use
So, can you plz help me out.

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved? I'm having the same exact issue with HostGator. I attempted removing all DLLs from the BIN, then started adding them one at a time and the error surface when I added Newtonsoft.json. How did you resolve this if you have?